# n coins. Which is fake?

Tags: math, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to find minimum number of weighings required to find defective ball from a set of n balls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234790/algorithm-to-find-minimum-number-of-weighings-required-to-find-defective-ball-fro)

We have n coins. One of them is fake, which is heavier or lighter (we don't know). We have scales with 2 plates. How can we get the fake coin in p moves?

Can you give me a hand for writing such a program? No need a whole program, just ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: I bet if a 1 reputation guy had asked a question like this, it would be downvoted and closed so fast.

Comment: What a hell are you talking about, Shawn?

Comment: @Shawn: It also got closed pretty fast when this guy asked it a few minutes ago: [48 coins. Which is fake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846670/48-coins-which-is-fake-closed)

Comment: ask over at programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [Balance puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_puzzle). See [Marcel Kołodziejczyk’s *Two-pan balance and generalized counterfeit coin problem*](http://math.uni.lodz.pl/~andkom/Marcel/Kule-en.pdf) for a generalization of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I remember solving this for n=12 and 13, partly by hand and then with a program at the end. I don't know how I would solve it for a general n... but I know how I'd *start* - by considering small values of `n` and doing it by hand.

I suspect there are essentially patterns that can be used recursively for this... but you'll find them much easier to discover with pen and paper for small values (n=4 to 7, for example) than by coding.

Answer (score 0):

Put coins on each side, the real ones will balance each other out, the fake will make the scale go either way. When the scales aren't balanced, one of the 2 you just put on is fake, try each against a real coin.

If the coins are objects you're handed, then you should be able to do that in a program quite easily.